# return index from a vector of the value closest to a given element

Tags: r

I have a list of elements such as

```
A=
  0.992688
  0.892195
  0.889151
  0.380672
  0.180576
  0.685028
  0.58195
```

Given an input element, like 0.4, how can I find the index that holds the number being most near to this number. For instance, `A[4] = 0.380672`  is most near to 0.4. Therefore, it should return to 4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

one way:

```
# as mnel points out in his answer, the difference,
# using `which` here gives all indices that match
which(abs(x-0.4) == min(abs(x-0.4)))
```

where `x` is your vector.

Alternately,

```
# this one returns the first index, but is SLOW
sort(abs(x-0.4), index.return=T)$ix[1]
```

Answer (score 14):

I would use `which.min`

```
which.min(abs(x-0.4))
```

This will return the  first index of the closest number to `0.4`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `base::findInterval(0.4, x)`